# Best way to update a list of structs

Tags: elixir

Let's say that I have a list of structs, with an `id` as one of its keys:

```
users = [
  %User{id: 1, attempts: 5},
  %User{id: 2, attempts: 12},
  %User{id: 3, attempts: 2}
]
```

What would the best way (the most elixir way) to update the number of attempts to 99 of the user with `id == 2` to get a new users list:

```
updated_users = [
  %User{id: 1, attempts: 5},
  %User{id: 2, attempts: 99},
  %User{id: 3, attempts: 2}
]
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```elixir
Enum.map(users, fn
  %User{id: 2} = user -> %User{user | attempts: 99}
  user -> user
end)
```

You can encapsulate it into some module and give it nice name :)

Comment: No problem. It would be good to point out that this is enumerates the whole list O(n) every time, so if being called multiple times it's much better to build a map, which is O(1). See my answer if interested.

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, most elixirish approach would be to use [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html) behaviour and [`Kernel.put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html?#put_in/3):

```rb
put_in users,
  [Access.filter(&match?(%User{id: 2}, &1)), 
   Access.key(:attempts)],
  99
#⇒ [
#  %User{attempts: 5, id: 1},
#  %User{attempts: 99, id: 2},
#  %User{attempts: 2, id: 3}
#]
```

---

This might be easily extended to update multiple elements by changing the filter function.

Comment: this is very hard to read, any reason to use this instead of map function?

Comment: @Daniel I don’t find it hard to read, but anyway. Yes, there is a reason to use it instead of `Enum.map/2`: it works for any depth, while `map` works only when structs are direct children of the top-level enumerable. It makes sense to get accustomed to use `Access` everywhere to a) get to read it easily and b) do not invent complicated `map`/`reduce` monsters when it comes to deeply nested terms. `Access` approach given an incredible flexibility.

Comment: @Daniel maybe this example would tell you “why `Access`” better than a ton of words: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58822419/2035262

Comment: yeah I noticed it few minutes ago, I guess the problem was not it was hard to read but the fact that it was the first time I saw it. Nor in starting guide, neither in a lot of examples there was not even a single mention of this, guess the only way was to look at the documentation.

Comment: @Daniel or—alternatively—to write your own library extensively dealing with deeply nested structures :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing many updates, it's probably best to build a map, so that you don't have to iterate the list for each update.

```elixir
[
  %User{attempts: 5, id: 1},
  %User{attempts: 12, id: 2},
  %User{attempts: 2, id: 3}
]
|> Map.new(fn user -> {user.id, user} end)
|> Map.update!(2, &%User{&1 | attempts: 99})
|> Map.values()
```

You can do as many [`Map.update!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update!/3) calls as you need, to update different ids.