# Replace item in an array in elixir

Tags: elixir

Let's say I have a map that looks like this

An organization has an array of properties and the properties has an array of "access_tokens"

```
organization = %{
  name: "Org",
  properties: [
    %{
      name: "prop1",
      access_tokens: [%{id: "at-1", name: "one-1"}, %{id: "at-2", name: "one-2"}]
    },
    %{
      name: "prop2",
      access_tokens: [%{id: "at-3", name: "two-1"}, %{id: "at-4", name: "two-2"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I have this map, for one particular access token, the id for this one matches one of the access tokens for the 2nd property:

```
access_token = %{id: "at-3", name: "new name"}
```

What is the best way to iterate over to update the `organization%{}` map with the new access token? What I want to do is find the access token that matches based on `id` and replace it with the new one that has the new name.

I have some round-about ways of doing this, but what is a clean way to do this in Elixir.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to iterate, just use [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html), [`Access.filter/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html#filter/1), and [`Access.all/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html#all/0):

```
put_in(
  organization,
  [:properties,
   Access.all(),
   :access_tokens,
   Access.filter(&match?(%{id: "at-3"}, &1)),
   :name],
  "new_name")
```

---

I always wonder, how this one of the most powerful things in the language is extremely underrated.

Comment: @7stud No one single language I am aware of provides such an elegant way of accessing deeply nested elements _with an ability to filter them on each level_ and there is a great documentation available. Note, that if `prop1` also had the matched element, it’d be updated too.

Comment: *there is a great documentation* -- Then perhaps you could explain why you always use `put_in()` instead of `update_in()`, which would seem to be the more logical choice.

Comment: Super cool, thank you! That is so useful!

That works, but it looks like it's not working if "at-3" is a variable `put_in(organization,[:properties, Access.all(), :access_tokens, Access.filter(&match?(%{id: access_token.id}, &1)), :name], "new_name")`

Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: I'm not sure where I would find this in the docs, but it seems that the Elixir convention is to use `put` anywhere you want to say "this key is now associated with this value" and an `update` anywhere you want to say "I want to do this operation on the value associated with this key (increment a counter, prepend to a list, etc.)". In this example, `put_in` makes more sense because we want `name: "new_name"` in our map. We would use `update_in` if we wanted a pair more like `name: "two-1-new_name"`. Essentially I'd use `put_in` anywhere you'd throw out the argument to the `update_in` callback.

Comment: @dylanjha Where `match?(pattern, expr)` is a macro, it won't like trying to match on your `new_at.id`. You could save that as a variable and pin it: `&match?(%{id: ^new_id}, &1)`, or you could filter with a simpler function: `& &1 == new_at.id`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @7Stud because I am putting the new value, not updating the old one, obviously.